# Is it possible to jar a spring application?

Tags: spring, maven-plugin, executable-jar

I have a web application in spring and hibernate and maven. I want to package my services and create a jar so that when main method is invoked, it will take the spring configurations from class path and it will call the services.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, for sure! There are 3 choices in front of you:

1. Spring boot http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/
2. Maven shade plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/
3. Maven assembly plugin http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Recommended is Spring boot, if it is possible, otherwise maven shade plugin is a good choice.. assembly plugin works also..